# Omitting subscripts in proofs/equations in math/computer science papers

Tags: publications, mathematics, computer-science, formatting

I am writing a paper that is in two column format, and I am working on a proof that I am having trouble making readable in the two column format.

Specifically, I am working with subscripts such as t-1, t, and t+1, but the subscripts t-1 and t+1 make the equations too long. If I omit the subscripts, then the proof is not clear, if I include the subscripts, the equations span many lines...

I am not sure what I should do.

Note: I am not sure if this is a proper stack exchange site.

Edit: I am deriving a function that looks like this x_{i+k} = g(x_i,\theta_{i,i+k}) where $\theta_{i,i+k}$ is a complicated parameter that take x_i to x_{i+k}. I derived earlier in the paper a recurrence x(i+1) = g(x_i, a, b, ...). So, in the proof, I am showing how to compute \theta_{i,i+k}.

Comment: It's difficult to advise on the formatting of equations without a concrete example. There are likely some tricks that you can use, but they really depend on your equations. Can you give a equation?

Comment: One solution is to bundle equations into a two-column figure.

Comment: @user2768 The equation is complex, but I edited my question to include the general idea if that is helpful.

Comment: Are you truly obliged to write in two-column format? Two-column format generates constant problems of this sort for mathematical expressions...

Comment: Do [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/one-column-equation-in-twocolumn-document-class) help?

Comment: *A* proper stack exchange site or *the* proper stack exchange site? If the former, then yes we are :) if the latter, you may find some useful info at tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you split the equation into two or more lines, using the "align" or "multline" environments?

Comment: @AndreasBlass As of right now, I split the equation in multiple lines, but the expression is a fraction, so I am writing it as [...][...]^{-1}. I use the “align”.

Comment: If you're using LaTeX, APS journals typically accept the widetext environment to span the two columns, which is available from revtex. You could try that out, although your specific publisher may not accept it.

Comment: Have you tried using different notation? Using both superscripts and subscripts can help, although you want to make sure things are both visually and conceptually readable, as you mentioned. Maybe set \theta_i^k := \theta_{i,i+k}?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ideas from a physics perspective. We often have to deal with long equations.

If you have the occasional over-long equation, then sparing use of the two-column environment or slightly smaller font size can be the good choices. (Assuming the journal accepts it.) Suppressing meaningful indices like this can be OK if they are repeated, but if the same equation contains both t-1, and t+1 you probably want to avoid it since it reduces clarity. A great alternative is to abstract more. Define new symbols containing part of your expressions, so that each shown equation becomes shorter - and if done right, easier to interpret. Of course, this comes at the cost of a higher total number of equations.

Finally, sometimes it's best to put a simplified equation in the main paper, and full expressions in the appendices. However, if the proof is central to your paper you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: In addition, physics journals know how to typeset long equations that stretch across the full page, so really one should leave it up to the journal layout folks.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The journal does not allow reducing font size. Unfortunetely, I do have t-1, t, and t+1 in a single equation. Typically, if I just have t and t+1, I use for example x and x'. I suppose I could add additional prime symbols e.g., x', x'', x'''. In this particular proof I don't have exponents for those terms.